# Vue: How to re-render view midway through event loop cycle?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqbaXE?editors=1010

I'd like `value` to display as "B" *immediately* after you click the button, and then display as "C" after a huge loop finishes. How can I accomplish this? Currently it never displays as "B".

In my actual application, I am running a bunch of simulations. When the user clicks "Simulate", I need to: change the text to say "Simulating...", run the simulations, and then change the text back to say "Simulate".

I've tried [Vue.nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue), [vm.$forceUpdate](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate), and `setTimeout(fn, 0)`, but none seem to work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="example">
  <p>Value: {{ message }}</p>
  <button v-on:click="change()">Change</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    message: 'A'
  },
  methods: {
    change: change
  }
})

function change () {
  vm.message = 'B';
  
  setTimeout(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++) {}
    vm.message = 'C';
  }, 0);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` works for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VrZqRa?editors=1010

Also, never do huge for loops like that in JavaScript: they will completely freeze your event loop (which needs to handle both javascript and user interactions).

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. My question is how to deal with the situation where you _do_ have the huge loop. In my particular application, I am running a bunch of simulations. When the user clicks Simulate, I'd like to 1) Give feedback that it is simulating, 2) Run the simulations, 3) Show the results of the simulations.

Comment: The DOM can only be updated after your setTimeout call returns, so do the modification of `vm.message` in one `setTimeout`, and your simulations in another. Even better, run your simulations using a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) so your UI remains responsive.

Comment: Two `setTimeout`s doesn't work for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPOewG?editors=1010. As for Web Workers, if it works I'd take it. I'm trying to reproduce the scenario using Web Workers right now. But it does sorta seem like overkill.

Comment: Web Workers does solve the problem! https://plnkr.co/edit/l93HpDsIEgaA6EjyMorN?p=preview I'm going to keep the question open for a bit though, because I'd like to see if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: If I delay the second `setTimeout` by a few milliseconds, it works.

Comment: Delaying the second `setTimeout` by a few milliseconds works for me also, thanks. Do you know why that is? Without the delay, shouldn't it work as follows: 1) First `setTimeout` gets added to the queue, 2) Second `setTimeout` gets added to the queue, 3) Execution finishes 4) First `setTimeout` is pushed to the stack, 5) First `setTimeout` is executed now that it is on the stack which updates the DOM to show "B", 6) First `setTimeout` is popped off the stack, 7) Second `setTimeout` is pushed to the stack, 8) Second `setTimeout` is executed which updates the DOM to show "C".

Comment: It is possible the browser groups `setTimeout` calls that are close to each other in time, to save on flickering when you make consequent DOM updates